# Creating a new folder upon image modification

Tags: python, computer-vision

I am supposed to write a function that reads all images from a given path, drops the green channel from the image, and writes it as a new image.

I managed to work out dropping the green channel and writing the modifications but currently the original images are being overwritten.

How do I modify the code below for the function to write new files?

```
def drop_green_from_path(path):
    for i in path:
        src = cv2.imread(i,cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
        #
        # assign green channel to zeros
        src[:,:,1] = np.zeros([src.shape[0], src.shape[1]])

        #save image
        cv2.imwrite(i ,src)

# will be changed later to be more global for now its at test on my laptop
DATA_IMAGES_PATHS= glob.glob('../data/train/train-1-0/*.png')
drop_green_from_path(DATA_IMAGES_PATHS)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to re-define the path in cv2.imwrite. That is,

```
import os

filesplit = os.path.split(i)
file_name = os.path.splitext(filesplit[1])[0]
file_ext = os.path.splitext(i)[1].lower()

file_name = file_name + "_modified" + file_ext

path = os.path.join(filesplit[0], file_name)

cv2.imwrite(path ,src)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would make it

```
import os, cv2
import numpy as np
def drop_greens(path):
    filenames = glob.glob(f'{path}/*.tif') # your extension(s)
    for filename in filenames:
        img = cv2.imread(filename)
        name = filename.split('.')[0]
        img[...,1]=0
        cv2.imwrite(f'{name}_modified.tif', img)
drop_greens(yourPath)
```